# How to design a POST request for file conversion correctly?

Tags: python, post, file-upload, python-requests, developer-tools

I found out that requests library can upload file on website by POST request (below is an example from the documentation)

```
   url = 'https://httpbin.org/post'
   files = {'file': open('report.xls', 'rb')}
   r = requests.post(url, files=files)
```

But I don't understand totally  how to apply this to my issue.I have website https://smallpdf.com/excel-to-pdf (just an example, the site may be different) and I need to upload the excel file and get the converted one by requests library.I would appreciate an explanation of how to correctly make a POST request based on the developer tools in the browser, what arguments to pass, and so on.
THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

Most of the Online Converters may not allow bots to enter their sites.
Thereby, use an Online Api which supports this to do your tasks. Here you can use [ConvertApi](https://www.convertapi.com/). It is documented [here](https://www.convertapi.com/xlsx-to-pdf).